# WCF post a byte[] to service?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, http-post

I'm trying to post a byte[] or FromBase64String string to my webservice. I keep getting the 404 error. I've changed the ["Content-type"] to "text/plain" and still get the error. However when I comment out the byteArray everything is fine. Does anyone have suggestions?

Client:

```
      Object _object = new Object
        {
            Param1String = "data",
            Param2String= "data",           
            Param3String = "data",
            ByteArray = ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Folder\test.pdf")
        };

        try
        {
            WebClient Proxy = new WebClient();                
            Proxy.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";                
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Object));
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, _object);
            byte[] data = Proxy.UploadData("http://localhost:4589/TestService.svc/FileUpload", "POST", stream.ToArray());

            stream = new MemoryStream(data);
            serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Object));
            var result = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as Object;
            Console.WriteLine(result.Param1String);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Service:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/FileUpload")]
    void FileUpload(Patron patron);

    public void FileUpload(Object patron)
    {

            byte[] newBytes = null;
            BinaryWriter Writer = null;
            string Name = @"C:\\Temp\\" + object.Param1String + "";
            //byte[] bData = Helper.CopyToArray(object.ByteArray);

            try
            {
                newBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(patron.ByteArray);
                Writer = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(Name));                    
                Writer.Write(newBytes);
                Writer.Flush();
                Writer.Close();
            }
            catch
            {                    
                //return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to base64 encode the filecontent before you serialize the object. and convert it back to byte[] on the other side

```
Object _object = new Object
    {
        Param1String = "data",
        Param2String= "data",           
        Param3String = "data",
        Base64ByteArray =  Convert.ToBase64String(ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Folder\test.pdf"))
    };
```